# How to enclose json attribute in double quotes within python?

Tags: python, json, regex

I am trying to make a string JSON compliant by enclosing the attribute into double quotes within python3 so I can parse the JSON.

The regex seems not to work as intended:

```
re.sub(r"/(?:[\w]+(?=:))/g", "", var)
```

String for variable `var`:

```
{
    pzn: "09900426",
    url: "/url.html",
    packageSizeValue: "28",
    packageSizeUnit: "St",
    sizeValue: "",
    potency: ""
}, {
    pzn: "09900432",
    url: "/url2.html",
    packageSizeValue: "84",
    packageSizeUnit: "St",
    sizeValue: "",
    potency: ""
}
```

Expected result would be:

```
{
    "pzn": "09900426",
    "url": "/url.html",
    ...
```

Comment: You wanted to use `re.sub(r"\w+(?=:)", r'"\g<0>"', var)`. This is not safe, imagine `potency: "blh:blah:"` value. Maybe `r"(?m)^(\s*)(\w+):"` and `r'\1"\2":'` as replacement would be safer (if the file is indented like that).

Comment: Nice! Yes that worked, can you please add an answer and if possible explain the regex a bit. So others (me included) can learn from it.

Comment: It would be better to examine *why* you have something that's almost-but-not-quite-JSON first, and see if you can fix whatever is producing it to produce proper JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look as though you wanted to use

```py
re.sub(r"\w+(?=:)", r'"\g<0>"', var)
```

The `\w+(?=:)` pattern matches any one or more word chars before a `:`, and the match is replaced with itself enclosed with double quotation marks. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9WqWf/2).

This is not safe because there can be such matches inside string values. Imagine a `potency: "blah:blah:"` value. In this case, it would be safer to leverage the indentation and use

```py
re.sub(r"(?m)^(\s*)(\w+):", r'\1"\2":', var)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9WqWf/1). Here,

- `(?m)` - equivalent of `re.M` `/` re.MULTILINE` option
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\s*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon.